# Function not returning value ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Here the **requestOptions()** function is calling from **init()** function and the console log requestoptions is even printing the value of options. But the return options statement is not working. Because when I try to console log the value of options in init() function, it is not printing anything. Why is it so? This is in ionic 3.9 and Angular 5 version

```
 private requestOptions(
  httpRequest: HttpRequestModel,
  options?: RequestOptions
 ): RequestOptions {
 options = new RequestOptions();
 options.body = httpRequest.body;
 options.params = httpRequest.params;
 options.method = httpRequest.method;
 console.log("requestoptions1", JSON.stringify(options));
 if (httpRequest.token == "true") {
  let token = this.AuthUserIdentity.getToken();
  this.headers.delete("token");
  this.headers.append("token", token);
 }
 let token = this.AuthUserIdentity.getDeviceToken();
 this.headers.delete("device_token");
 this.headers.append("device_token", token);
 options.headers = this.headers;
 console.log("requestoptions", JSON.stringify(options));
 return options;
}

init(httpRequest: HttpRequestModel): Observable<any> {
  let options;
  console.log("inittt", httpRequest);
  options = this.requestOptions(httpRequest);
  console.log(
    "APIII",
    this.baseUrl + httpRequest.url,
    JSON.stringify(options)
  );
  return this.request(this.baseUrl + httpRequest.url, options);
}
```

Comment: Use chrome developer tools to debug what is preventing requestOptions to return value

Comment: This is working when I try to run the app on web using ionic serve, but in case of an android device or simulator it is not working.